# Identifying the cause of death

Tags: united-states, palaeography, death-records, cause-of-death, michigan

[image: Ancestors cause of Death]

This is a photo of my ancestors cause of death. For the life of me I cannot decipher what it says. If anyone has a good idea or even a hint of what it is please let me know!

Comment: Hi, Amanda, welcome to G&FH.SE!  In the future, it might help to include a bit more information in your question, such as the year the death took place.  That would allow us to give you more clues even if we couldn't read the document.

Answer (score 14):

The cause of death was:

> Haemorrhage from Duodenal ulcer